# Валидация формы по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.

Вопрос довольно нубский, но прошу помочь, так как JS только начал осваивать, а jQuery вообще еще не вникал.

Есть страница, с готовой валидацией инпутов (радио) на выбраны они или нет. Если ответы не выбраны - кнопка по умолчанию `disabled` и текст `Please, give answers to all questions`. Если выбраны - идем дальше.

Но валидация работает в общем по странице.

Надо как то ее переделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку `submit` запускалась проверка валидности. Если все ок - запускаем `action="http://google.com"`, если нет - показываем сообщение из `span.warning-text`. Ну и никакого `disabled` на кнопке не использовать уже.

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- RADIO SELECTION VALIDATION SCRIPT-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a01 = $('input[name=answer-1]');
  var a02 = $('input[name=answer-2]');
  var a03 = $('input[name=answer-3]');
  var a04 = $('input[name=answer-4]');
  var a05 = $('input[name=answer-5]');
  
  validate();
  
  $("input[type='radio']").change(validate);
  
  function validate() {
    if ($(a01).is(':checked') && $(a02).is(':checked') && $(a03).is(':checked')&& $(a04).is(':checked')&& $(a05).is(':checked')) {
        $(".btn#submit").removeAttr("disabled", false);
        $(".warning-result-text").css("opacity", '0');
    } else {
        $(".btn#submit").attr("disabled", true);
    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
<form class="get-result-form" action="http://google.com">
  <span class="warning-text">Please, give answers to all questions</span>
  <input class="btn btn-submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit answers" disabled="true">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил этот вопрос так:

```js
$('.get-result-form').submit(function valForm() {
        var a01 = $('input[name=answer-1]');
        var a02 = $('input[name=answer-2]');
        var a03 = $('input[name=answer-3]');
        var a04 = $('input[name=answer-4]');
        var a05 = $('input[name=answer-5]');
        
        validate();
        
        $("input[type='radio']").change(validate);
        
        function validate() {
         if ($(a01).is(':checked') && $(a02).is(':checked') && $(a03).is(':checked')&& $(a04).is(':checked')&& $(a05).is(':checked')) {
                   this.submit();
         } else {
              $(".warning-result-text").css("opacity", '1');
              event.preventDefault();
         }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Валидацию проверять надо на php либо js клиентский язык и его обмануть проще 
отправляй данные на серв и проверяй там если все ок он перекинет дальше,если нет перекинет тебя на эту же страницу и сданными об ошибке.

Comment: Буду очень признателен, если подскажите как это реализовать с помощью PHP.

Comment: отправляешь `$_POST` в фаил где будет проверка  берешь нужный импут например(`$_POST['Language']`) и в if проверяешь
потом `header` `ом перекидываешь куда надо ,если например неправедно даем сессию и с этой сессий идешь на ту же страницу откуда отправлял запрос через сессию делаешь появление ошибки опять же через проверку